# How can I make a behavior similar to useParams(NextJS) in vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I have a question. How can I make a behavior similar to [useParams()](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params) of NextJS in vanilla JS?
For example, my code is the following (It's not preact or react. It's from a small project I'm doing)

This is my Navigation ([this is the repo](https://github.com/UnSetSoft/Ryunixjs/tree/dev/packages/ryunix)):

```
import { useStore, useEffect } from './hooks'
import { createElement } from './createElement'
const Router = ({ path, component }) => {
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useStore(window.location.pathname)

  useEffect(() => {
    const onLocationChange = () => {
      setCurrentPath(() => window.location.pathname)
    }

    window.addEventListener('navigate', onLocationChange)
    window.addEventListener('pushsatate', onLocationChange)
    window.addEventListener('popstate', onLocationChange)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('navigate', onLocationChange)
      window.removeEventListener('pushsatate', onLocationChange)
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', onLocationChange)
    }
  }, [currentPath])

  return currentPath === path ? component() : null
}

const Navigate = (props) => {
  if (props.style) {
    throw new Error(
      'The style attribute is not supported on internal components, use className.',
    )
  }
  if (props.to === '') {
    throw new Error("'to=' cannot be empty.")
  }
  if (props.className === '') {
    throw new Error('className cannot be empty.')
  }
  if (props.label === '' && !props.children) {
    throw new Error("'label=' cannot be empty.")
  }

  if (!props.to) {
    throw new Error("Missig 'to' param.")
  }
  const preventReload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (window.location.pathname !== props.to) {
      window.history.pushState({}, '', props.to)
      const navigationEvent = new Event('pushsatate')
      window.dispatchEvent(navigationEvent)
    }
  }

  const anchor = {
    href: props.to,
    onClick: preventReload,
    ...props,
  }

  const children = props.label ? props.label : props.children

  return createElement('a', anchor, children)
}

export { Router, Navigate }
```

the general idea would be like this  and from my post.jsx file I could use something similar to useParams() to consume what  constructs.

```
/post/[slug]/[id]?a=b&c=d

getParams => {
   slug: "hello-world",
   id: 1,
   query: {
    a: "b",
    c: "d"
   }
}


import {getParams} = "..."

const Post = () => {
   const { slug, id } = getParams()
}
```

Clearly my project has a long way to go before I can get the navigation to work decently, but I wanted to see an easy way to do it with what I have.

one way that I thought is this, but then in practice it gave problems, since  is not prepared for /[slug]/[id].

```
// get numeric ID's only

const idRegex =  /\d+/g;
const url = "http://example.com/hello/world/page/3"
const info = new URL(url)

console.log(info.pathname.match(idRegex)) // ["3"]

// params
const regex = /([^\-0-9/]+)/g;
const url = "http://example.com/hello/world/page/3/hey"
const info = new URL(url)

console.log(info.pathname.match(regex)) // ["hello", "world", "page", "hey"]
```